# Nodejs Cache static file content in variable

Tags: node.js, express

I want to read all of my static files and save to an Array. (I have just 10 files, css, js, jpg, and fonts)

And for each requests, I want to just send variable content to response instead of read file content from hard disk each time.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const {readFile} = require('fs/promises');

let startPath="./public";

const { readdir } = require('fs').promises;

const getFileList = async (dirName) => {
    let files = [];
    const items = await readdir(dirName, { withFileTypes: true });

    for (const item of items) {
        if (item.isDirectory()) {
            files = [
                ...files,
                ...(await getFileList(`${dirName}/${item.name}`)),
            ];
        } else {
            files.push(`${dirName}/${item.name}`);
        }
    }

    return files;
};

let filesContent=[];


getFileList(startPath).then(async (files) => {
    for(const item of files)
    {
        filesContent[item]= await readFile(item);
    }
});


app.get('*', async (req,res) => {
    if(filesContent[startPath+req._parsedUrl.pathname]!==undefined)
    {
        res.send(filesContent[startPath+req._parsedUrl.pathname]);
    }
    else
    {
        let content=await readFile(path.join(__dirname,startPath+req._parsedUrl.pathname));

        filesContent[startPath+req.url]=content;
        
        res.send(content);
    }
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I have a problem. I need save exactly response for res.sendFile in [content] variable.

This code just save file content in variable.

```
let content=await readFile(path.join(__dirname,startPath+req._parsedUrl.pathname));
```

But I need exactly save `res.sendFile` to my variable.

Comment: What are you doing? You're using `express`, it has static hosting _built in_. Just tell it which directory to use as part of the [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) call.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks. Yes, I know. I want to save static files content in memory (Array variable). and next request response from variable, instead of read file content from hard disk.

Comment: So that's not really static content then. But the real question is: "why?". What problem do you think you're solving by doing this rather than by just serving your static files the normal way?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am under DDOS Attack. So I want to return static file from memory. Instead of read every request from Hard Disk

Comment: And why do you think that would help against a DDoS attack?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So if don't read from hard disk, It was so better :-)

Comment: Only until the botnet goes "this site's still up, add more connections per second" and you're right back to the original problem.